# Forward all DAHDI channels to another server [FreePBX]

Tags: asterisk, voip, dahdi

here is my problem:

after installing and configuring a 12 port FXO card ( from openvoc.cn ) i found that according to openvox support that this FXO card is not supported on my system ( some of there FXO cards dose not work well on AMD motherboards ).

so as workaround i moved the card to another Intel Motherboard and installed and configured asterisk + freepbx, and is working fine..

problem is: the AMD server is my development server, also for a some reasons i want the sip phones to connect to the AMD server, not the Intel with the FXO there.

is there a way ( temporary until i get another FXO card ) to do this:

1- Forward all the incoming calls on the FXO ports to go to the AMD server, as if the card was installed on the AMD server, and from there freepbx can handle the calls?

2- add trunks on the AMD server to use the FXO installed on the intel server? <-- this i think it can be done from the add trunk page, but not sure how.

basically what i want is to use this FXO card which is installed on another server is if it was installed locally.

what is the cleanest and best method to do this?
the idea is that i don't want a complicated setup, because the main reason for this server is to learn asterisk & freepbx, and want a clean start.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need connect 2 servers as described in this article

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Connect+2+servers

Or in any asterisk's book. For example ORelly's "Asterisk the future of telephony" is ok for you.

After that you have setup dialplan to call your trunks(if you use freepbx set for inbound context=from-internal),setup dahdi channels to call your AMD box(in freepbx in dahdi channels tab)